# (React Native) App always crash at a certain page

Tags: react-native

This is the link to my app which is in progress :https://snack.expo.io/@demonicaoi/cash-trackerro

When I scanned the qr code of the app using my phone(an android model), ALL my pages seemed to be fine. However, at the route 'Category, which is in CategoryScreen.js, the app will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The problem lies with the style `category_screen.title`.

If you remove that style, category screen is rendering perfectly. I tried with a dummy style={{ color: 'red' }}

**Edit**

The error was 'Text strings must be rendered within a  component'

I removed that line, and typed it back, and it worked. Now with your actual style `category_screen.title` is working fine.

https://snack.expo.io/@rajeshde422/6258d6

Comment: thanks! although i just figured out that i made a mistake in my stylesheet, which resulted in the crash